# What can provide immunity to dehydration?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

My party is working through Castle Whiterock and we just got clobbered by a group of lions with Goodman Games desiccated template.  This template allows for a D6 Con damage on every hit (no save) except if the creatures have immunity to dehydration.  Are there items or spells that are available to a party with a 9th level cleric, paladin, and ranger that might provide just that?  Pathfinder of D&D 3.X solutions are fine we're pulling material from both.

Comment: Alternately if anyone knows if the desiccated template really allows for straight Con damage on an attack that might be useful to know.

Comment: Yep! Straight CON damage on every attack. Welcome to first edition feel...

Comment: So I did some more research on the Goodman Games board and this is actually incorrect.  They omitted the Fort save.  I found the book the template was in on DriveThruRPG as a double verify.  Part of me was kinda sad that it wasn't actual CON damage but considering how challenging that would make the encounter I'll live (and so will the party!)

Comment: A lot of water?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There look to be two spells of partial utility in Sandstorm:

- [Protection from Dessication](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/spells.php?ID=5919)
- <strike>[Skin of the Cactus](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/spells.php?ID=5924)</strike>

Skin of the cactus only prevents non-lethal desiccation damage. Protection from Dehydration (Cleric 3, Druid 2, ranger 2, sor/wis 3, summer 3) does *exactly* what you want. First line states that it grants immunity to dehydration of any kind (given that that is what the attack does... that's a good start.) And it protects against both dehydration and dessication damage up to 100 points (10/level), without noting what kind of damage.

This is your best bet from traditional sources, and should be sufficiently effective without being overpowered to be allowed.